# Use Composer CLI to add data to the extra property

Tags: php, composer-php, command-line-interface

According to the documentation of the `extra` property of the [composer.json schema](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#extra), allows setting of "arbitrary extra data for consumption by scripts."

For scripting purposes, it would be nice if data can be added to the `extra` property via the command-line. It have tried `composer config extra.foo bar`, but this gives the error `Setting extra.foo does not exist or is not supported by this command`.

So I was wondering: is there a way to use the Composer CLI to add data to the `extra` property?

UPDATE: Composer 1.1.0 has added supported for this feature: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#modifying-extra-values
Unfortunately, it is not possible to add boolean or numeric values, as each value is added as a string. See also [issue #5492 of the Composer project](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5492).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Composer 1.1.0, it is is possible to add *string* values to the `extra` property using the CLI:

```
composer config extra.foo "some text"
composer config extra.bar 123
composer config extra.baz true
```

This results in the following:

```
"extra": {
    "foo": "some text",
    "bar": "123",
    "baz": "true"
}
```

As of Composer 2.0, it is possible to add values *in any JSON value type* using the `--json` and `--merge` flags. This includes the possibility to add numbers and booleans:

```
composer config --json extra.foo '"some text"'
composer config --json extra.bar 123
composer config --json extra.baz true
```

This results in the following:

```
"extra": {
    "foo": "some text",
    "bar": 123,
    "baz": true
}
```

The [documentation of this feature](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#modifying-extra-values) shows how you can add a JSON object from the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, and the reason is that this usually is bound to some very specific local use case that does not apply to the general audience.

All parameters that can be influenced with `composer config` are listed here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md

If you want to add data to the "extra" part, you have to edit it by hand or let your script do it in some other way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hoping that this was something that was missing in the Composer documentation, like the possibility of setting repositories via composer config.

Comment: The easiest way I have found to add extra properties to the composer.json, is to use jq, a cli JSON processor. In combination with sponge, you can do in place editing: jq --indent 4 '.extra.foo = "bar"' composer.json | sponge composer.json

Comment: the last comment should be the right answer .. what a nice oneliner! Impressive, thank you Aad

Comment: The current answer would be to use Composer 1.1 or higher. See the updated question's comment.