# How to pass a variable to composer.json through the command line

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, composer-php

How can I submit a variable when running `composer install` to be able to affect composer.json and modify "wp" depending of what I pass:

```
“extra”: {
    “wordpress-install-dir”: “wp” //This should be customizable via CLI
},
```

I'm using Composer to install Wordpress in a subdirectory -following https://deliciousbrains.com/how-why-install-wordpress-core-subdirectory/ method-.

```
{
    “name”: “polevaultweb/wp-composer-core-sub-dir”,
    “description”: “Installing WordPress in a subdirectory with Composer”,
    “require”: {
        “php”: “>=5.4”,
        “johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer”: “0.2.0”,
        “johnpbloch/wordpress”: “~4.2”
    },
    “extra”: {
        “wordpress-install-dir”: “wp”
    },
    “scripts”: {
        “post-install-cmd”: [
            “cp wp/index.php ./index.php”,
            “sed -i ‘’ \”s/\\/wp-blog-header/\\/wp\\/wp-blog-header/g\” index.php”
        ]
    }
}
```

I read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md and tried: `composer install run-script "WP_CORE=wpsubdirectory"` and then in my composer.json add a BASH variable:

```
  “extra”: {
        “wordpress-install-dir”: “$WP_CORE”
    },
```

It doesn't worked, because the syntax itself it's not well formated.

I'm quiet stuck. Anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568749/use-composer-cli-to-add-data-to-the-extra-property

Answer (score 4):

I solved it using the following command.

```
composer config extra.wordpress-install-dir --unset ; composer config extra.wordpress-install-dir WPSUBDIRECTORY ;
```

**What does it do?**

First, it removes the *wordpress-install-dir* value, if it exists. Then it adds *wordpress-install-dir* and sets it to *WPSUBDIRECTORY*.

```
"extra": {
  "wordpress-install-dir": "WPSUBDIRECTORY"
}
```

#### Reference

- [Modifying Extra Values](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#modifying-extra-values)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config variable "**version**"

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "version": "1.0.2",
     ...
     ...
 }
```

> For show current version

```
composer config version       //1.0.2
```

and If set new version

```
composer config version 1.0.3
```

> NOTE: If you can put your other data in composer.json then you can use
>   extra key in json

```
"extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        },
        "my-theme-color":{
           "color":"green"
        }
    },
```